# Relative vs absolute position css when working screen responive

Tags: css

What is the different between absolute and relative positions when you are using a screen responsive design?

Comment: Maybe you can check this link: http://learnlayout.com/position.html

Comment: It's not really relevant. Responsiveness would normally have little or nothing to do with positioning. Positioning is used for specific effects and is not usually required to create responsiveness.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. They work exactly the same way everywhere. Just because your containing elements may adapt to different sizes, an element being positioned still retains those properties and adjusts the same way.